# Cumulative Sum with Duplicate Date ms-access

Tags: ms-access-2010

i'm trying to calculate running sum for an account statement using ms-access query but i have problem when there is duplicate dates the sum is not changing until the date changes

this is the img link for results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUfa2.png

and this is the query :

```sql
SELECT Trans.TransDate, Trans.Cr, Trans.Dr, (SELECT SUM(t.[Dr]-t.[Cr]) FROM Trans t WHERE t.[TransDate]<= Trans.[TransDate] AND t.Account = Trans.Account) AS Balance
FROM Trans
WHERE (((Trans.Account)="Cash"))
ORDER BY Trans.TransDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a query without a unique key. For your sample, you might be able to include the amounts, but that will miss again should two or more records of the account also have the same amount.

In VBA, you could open the query as a recordset and loop the records while you add up the running sum.